# How to embed a flash object on my website?

Tags: html, flash, embed

Well, I must say this is embarrassing to ask, but to my defense I'll say that throughout my years of web development I've never encountered a case where embedding flash was absolutely necessary.

### The Question

- Simple, how do I embed a flash object of any kind (*.swf or if there any other options, them too) to my website?

### Some Points

- I don't need the code, I already have that, I just don't really understand it.
- I'm looking for a good explanation on how to use the `<embed>` or `<object>` elements.
- I've been searching around but couldn't find a clear explanation, even in the specs.

I'd award any good answer with an upvote, a cookie, and an accepted answer to the best :)

Comment: I don't know the *perfect* industry-standard solution for this either, but I'm hearing a lot of good things about http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/ (Requires JS, of course - but then, JS being turned off while Flash is active is probably *extremely* unlikely)

Comment: What's that? Could you explain? (I'm actually looking for an explanation on `<embed>` or other normal HTML only solutions)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Definitions:

http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/embed

http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/object

Explanation on how to embed a flash object from Adobe:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/415/tn_4150.html

"The HTML OBJECT tag directs the browser to load Adobe Flash Player and then use it to play your SWF file."

Comment: Terribly incomplete answer. So lazy and doesn't account for the asker's noob-ness.

Comment: @3Dom feel free to post a better one.

Comment: I almost didn't comment on this, but @3Dom... this is, technically, the correct answer, and I'm glad to see it's also the accepted one.  That you might use some JS library means nothing.  In the end, all that library does is (other than require JS to view flash) is drop one or the other of the HTML elements mentioned in this answer on the page.  So.  Your comment here shows YOUR noob-ness, provided "noob-ness" means not really understanding what was being asked anyway.

Comment: I always get criticized and voted down when I post responses such as that. The explanation is that the other site(s) might go away some day. Of course they ignore the possibility that something in StackOverlow can become obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

Change "YOURFILENAMEHERE.swf" with your .swf file name.

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="240" id="Yourfilename" ALIGN="">
<PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="YOURFILENAMEHERE.swf">
<PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high>
<PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#333399>
<EMBED src="Yourfilename.swf" quality=high bgcolor=#333399 WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="240" NAME="Yourfilename" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></EMBED></OBJECT>
```

Comment: "I don't need the code, I already have that, I just don't really understand it." :